# Обособление вводного слова перед подчинительным союзом в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, спп

Из художественной литературы:

***В самом деле, если** дали парашют, **то**, наверно, придется и прыгать.* Василь Быков. Болото (2001).

**По какому правилу** обособлено вводное слово?

Обратим внимание на **двойной** подчинительный союз ***ЕСЛИ...ТО***. Переставлять придаточное для проверки нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне *кажется*, что здесь "работает" обычное правило: "вводные слова и сочетания слов выделяются или отделяются запятыми".

У нас ***двойной подчинительный*** союз, а не сочинительный, поэтому ни о какой перестановке тут речи быть не может (§ 95. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, находясь рядом с сочинительными союзами, отделяются или не отделяются от них запятыми в зависимости от контекста).

У нас ***целое*** предложение, а не обособленный оборот, поэтому правило об обособленных членах предложения тут тоже не подходит (§ 93. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом...).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

***В самом деле, если** внимательно присмотреться к художникам авангарда, **то** мы увидим, что вместо изображения они конструируют образ* (Е. В. Петровская. Безымянные сообщества).

***Конечно, если** ты Александр Сергеевич, да ещё и в русскоговорящей стране, **то** тебе лучше быть Пушкиным* (Татьяна Соломатина. Девять месяцев, или «Комедия женских положений»).

***Кстати, если** плазма оторвётся от Солнца, **то** нам тут мало не покажется!* (Георгий Гречко, Артур Хазиев. «Красота и ранимость Земли» // «Зеркало мира»).

***Кажется, если** б не коровы, **то** отвела бы душу... наговорила б ему такого, что он два дня не очухался бы!* (Валентина Осеева. Динка прощается с детством).

***По сути, если** раньше главу управы избирали сами жители, **то** отныне его будет назначать мэр...* (Дмитрий Катаев: «Никто не собирается делить метро или канализацию»).

***Следовательно, если** в этой стране водилось золото, **то** большая часть его лежит на дне этого колодца* (А. М. Кондратов. Атлантиды ищите на шельфе).

[Знаки препинания при вводных словах, сочетаниях слов и предложениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127) (ПАС)

Comment: Вот именно. Так и есть.

Comment: @Максим Что же вы не ответили, если "вот именно, так и есть"? Вопрос был задан давно.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Спасибо. Вероятно, вы правы: начло предложения — это не пограничная зона между различными конструкциями, для которых надо применять правило. Напрягает еще то, что правила  РАЗНЫЕ. В ПАС вводное слово вроде бы относится к придаточному и не обособляется (§ 94), а у Розенталя оно выделяется запятыми на общих основаниях (п.7).  // В начале заданного предложения, вероятно,  может находиться и НАРЕЧИЕ, и здесь надо сделать выбор. Кстати, вводное слово в такой позиции вряд ли перейдет в парное наречие (например,  вводное слово «по сути»).

Comment: @Sharon Нет мотивации кому-либо отвечать)) Только изредка могу, если захочу.

Comment: Что так?  Что случилось с вашей мотивацией?)